glossary-extra toggles off acronyms in Abstract for a document
I'm using the package glossary-extra in my thesis and happen to use some acronyms in my Abstract. Now, I have a code-block that prevents the hyperlink to be active on multiple occurrences of the term after the first one.
However, as the Abstract is placed before the actual main document and I happen to use four acronyms in it, these are highlighted in the Abstract and not anymore for their first occurrence in-text.
So, my question is there is a way to exclude the Abstract from the count, or prevent glossary-extra to consider a part of the document while counting acronyms?
Below, a MWE. Let me know, thanks!
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[inkscapearea=page]{svg}
\usepackage[main=english, italian]{babel}
\usepackage[postdot,acronym,toc]{glossaries-extra}

%GLOSSARY TERMS AND ACRONYMS
\makeglossaries
\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{Page: }{Pages: }
\GlsXtrEnableLinkCounting{general,acronym}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\makefirstuc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\acrshort}[1][]{\glsxtrshort[#1]}
\renewcommand*{\acrshortpl}[1][]{\glsxtrshortpl[#1]}
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\color{black}{#1}}
% disable hyperlink if link count is greater than 1:
\renewcommand*{\glslinkpresetkeys}{%
 \ifnum\GlsXtrLinkCounterValue{\glslabel}>1
  \setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}%
 \fi
}

%EXAMPLE TERMS
\newglossaryentry{graph-topology}
{
    name=topology,
    description={collection of features and properties describing a graph data structure}
}

\newacronym{pca}{PCA}{Principal Component Analysis}
\newacronym{hifi}{HiFi}{High Fidelity, same as CCS}
\newacronym{snp}{SNP}{Single Nucleotide Polymorphism}
\newacronym{snv}{SNV}{Single Nucleotide Variant, same concept of SNP when working with a single sample instead of a panel}
\newacronym{indel}{INDEL}{INsertion-DELetion up to 49 base pairs}
\newacronym{sv}{SV}{Structural Variant}
\newacronym{hprc}{HPRC}{Human Pangenome Reference Consortium}
\newacronym{grch38}{GRCh38}{Genome Reference Consortium human Build 38}
\newacronym{chm13}{CHM13}{Chimera 13}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{italian}
\begin{abstract}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
In this section I'm using the following acronym: \acrshort{hprc}. And this one: \acrshort{chm13}, and this one: \acrshort{grch38} as well.
\end{abstract}
\end{otherlanguage}

\chapter{Introduction}

\dots this is what happens if I use the same acronyms in another part of the documents: \acrshort{hprc}, \acrshort{chm13} and \acrshort{grch38}.

\printglossary[title=Terminology, toctitle=Terminology]

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=List of Abbreviations, toctitle=List of Abbreviations]

\end{document}

